# Sorting with MongoDB compound indexes

Tags: performance, mongodb, sorting

I am thinking of using MongoDB and shifting my data from MySQL. I will use MongoDB's embedded arrays, and I added 100,000 sample documents. Here is the document's schema and some sample data:

```
array(
   "a" => array("a", "c", "d"),
   "b" => 200
)

array(
    "a" => array("b", "e", "d"),
    "b" => 300
)

array(
    "a" => array("f", "c", "d"),
    "b" => 400
)

array(
    "a" => array("o", "l", "g"),
    "b" => 500
)


array(
"a" => array("x","c","b"),
"b" => 600
)
```

A sample query would be this: To get all the x records between 200 and 500,

```
array("a" => "x", "b" => array('$gte' => 200, '$lte' => 500))
```

When I index (a,b) together and limit it to 10, I get " nscanned " and " n " 10 which is perfect. But, as I read from the articles, skipping costs much, so I have to sort them according to their " _id " and paginate next documents with '$gt'.

After this point I indexed (a,b,_id) together, and I tried reverse _id compound index combinations also. But (a,_id(-1),b) gave me the best result, but nscanned, is still too much. I read from the MongoDB documentation and it says if you put sorting field in compound indexes it will sort fine, but it did not sort fine. How can I manage this?